# how to build dependant packages across multiple machines

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosservice, dependencies, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package running a service (package A) and another running a client for that service (package B) both implemented in c++. Package B has build/exec dependency on package A for that service. Both compile and work fine when they are in the same workspace of a single machine.

Now if I want to run a distributed system and move package A on machine A and package B on machine B , what would be the best way to handle this build dependency?

or in other words, how can i build package B on machine B without having package A on that machine?

I am sorry if there is an obvious answer but I am having trouble researching this information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367710/how-to-build-dependant-packages-across-multiple-machines/) by [nikkoun](https://answers.ros.org/users/65589/nikkoun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> how can i build package B on machine B without having package A on that machine?

best practice would be to refactor package `A` into package `A` and a separate package which hosts just the messages/services/action definitions.

Then both `A` and `B` depend on the message package.

What you describe is the main rationale for doing that: you can build subscribers and clients without needing the packages containing the publishers or servers in the same workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0